# Override Menu Button action

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

The Nexus displays the screen as follows:(Here I press on the 3 dots on the top right corner to drop down the menu)

[image]

I have a menu appear at the top right corner of the screen.
The phone display the menu as follows(This happens only when I press the menu button on the phone) :

[image]

I would like to have the same menu behavior in phone as in the tablet where-in I can show the menu in the top right corner of the screen. My question here is that  is there any way to override the menu inflate behavior where-in the menu has to be displayed from the top right position of the screen even in the phone as well

Comment: You really shouldn't mess with the menu button. Different manufacturers have different solutions for the menu button and if you start moving it around the user will have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Moreover, on many phones, the action bar *will* be displayed in the upper right corner. It is not a question of phone vs. tablet but whether or not the device has a dedicated off-screen MENU button. Please help your users by accepting the default behavior and thereby following the pattern employed by all the other apps on their device.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your inputs. How will the user know that there is menu to select in the phone option?

Comment: "How will the user know that there is menu to select in the phone option?" -- the same way that they have for the past five years: they will know that they have a MENU button and will press it from time to time to see what happens. IMHO, this was never a great approach. However, it *is* the UI convention and what standard apps are set up to do. Users of devices with a MENU button may have been using that button for some time, and may not recognize a "..." affordance in an action bar as being somehow related.

Answer (score 5):

It is a little complicated, but here is the general idea :

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

}

In this method `v` is the view by which you want your menu to appear.

You will need to `Override` the menu button so that when the user presses it your menu appears. Do the following

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        //Put the code for an action menu from the top here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And then everything else is the same as it is for your normal menu(I think)

Comment: I would suggest onKeyUp event, as I've tried onKeyDown and my PopupMenu dissapeared as soon as I've released my menu button.